# How to Convert an array values into booleans values

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode6, boolean

I have an array like this

```
myArray=[0,0,1];
```

I want to convert this array values into boolean values like below

```
myArray=[false,false,true];
```

I assign array values into strings

```
mystring=[myarray objectAtIndex:0];
```

if possible here also i can convert the 0, 1s into boolean values.

Comment: `myArray=[false,false,true];` This is not a value array in Obj-C. The objects should confine to type `id`

Comment: myArray=[0,0,1]; is not valid either, should be myArray=[@0,@0,@1];

Comment: [myArray[0] booleanValue]; should give you the boolean values (YES/NO)

Comment: `myArray=[@0,@0,@1]` is not valid either, should be `myArray=@[@0,@0,@1]`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the way you store the value. Whatever number you store bigger than one, it will be considered as `YES` when you retrieve as `BOOL` type. However, it will give you the actual number if you retrieve it as `NSInteger` or `int`. So, use `booleanValue` method to retrieve like so:

```
NSNumber *value1 = myArray[0];
BOOL boolValue1 = [value1 booleanValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is in the code below:

```
// Do nothing
```

The long answer is like this:

You do not have an array as you described. The correct code would be:

```
myArray=@[ @0, @0, @1]; // NSArray instance of NSNumber instances.
```

You do not want to have an array as you described. The correct code would be:

```
myArray=@[ @NO, @NO, @YES]; // NSArray instance of NSNumber instances.
```

Since both `NSNumber` instances containing integer values or boolean values [are the same](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/), `[@0 boolValue]` will return `NO` and `[@1 boolValue]` will return `YES`. So you already have, what you want to get.

Your real problem is the translation of values (integer or boolean, while boolean values *are* integer values) into a string. You can use a number formatter for this or simply a conditional expression:

```
BOOL b = [myarray[0] boolValue];
mystring = b?@"true":@"false";
```